# Is our use case suitable for a NoSQL Database solution?

Tags: database-design, mongodb, nosql

We are currently running a Python web app querying a SQL MariaDB (through SQLAlchemy). Unfortunately we have run into some hard limitations of MariaDB (number of joins are [limited to 61](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/joins-limits.html)) and are looking for alternatives. Our database is not very large (generally under 2GB and growing slowly) and the entries could actually very well be broken down to simple json objects, which made us look at a NoSQL solution.

Initially this seemed like a great solution. Queries were super fast (as the DB fit into RAM) and we were happy (for a few days).

**I came here to seek advice if the NoSQL DB is a recommended solution for our needs, though.** So let's talk about the data:

The nature of our data is that multiple group of entries / rows generally reference back to the same object, pretty much as if you had multiple versions that relate to a single object.

Assume a document entry could look like this:

```
_id: 5a31...
description: Object
    location: "XYZ"
    name: "ABC"
    status: "A"
    m_nr: null
    k_nr: null
    city: "QWE"
    high_value: 17
    right_value: 71
more_data: Object
    number: 101
    interval: 1
    next_date: "2016-01-16T00:00:00Z"
    last_date: null
    status: null
classification: Object
    priority_value: "?"
    redundancy_value: "?"
    active_value: "0"
```

Imagine the `description.location` will often need to be grouped and sorted so that I can only display the `$last` entry for each of these grouped entries. A common query may look like this (in `MongoDB`):

```
db.getCollection('a').aggregate(
    [{ $sort:
        {"description.location": 1}
     },
     { $group:
        {_id: "$description.location"}
     }]
)
```

I have unfortunately found that this particular query takes very long, when the DB does not fit into memory - even **with an index** for `description.location` present in the MongoDB. (For some reason the `$group` aggregation operation never appears to be using the available index, while `$sort` actually does use it).

Either way, is this data / layout / query strategy something that resonates well with a NoSQL DB ?

Comment: Not saying your data can't fit into a NoSQL solution, but if you're looking to move from RDBMS because of a `JOIN` limit then I think you're addressing the problem wrong. While 61 isn't impossible, I'd start with looking at if you really need to do that big of a query all at once and possibly evaluate other RDBMS products. NoSQL will be an *entirely* different beast all-around. It is no trivial thing to jump into a whole different, much younger (MongoDB specifically), database product type.

Comment: Thank you. We generally agree and are evaluating PostgreSQL as well as our query / table strategy, but due to the limitations of our cloud provider for out-of-the-box solutions (read: no PostgreSQL, only MariaDB), we are technically limited to what they offer. To be fair, I can of course deploy my own PostgreSQL server, but it won’t be smooth sailing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see your interest in JSON objects.

> Our database is not very large (generally under 2GB and growing
>   slowly) and the entries could actually very well be broken down to
>   **simple json objects**, which made us look at a NoSQL solution.

**MongoDB** is better suited for huge databases, in your case, I suggest  **PostgreSQL**.

You can use JSON types in PostgreSQL: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html

Should be easy enough to migrate your app to PostgreSQL, because it's SQL all the way, and I doubt that you will find that stupid join limit.

> Either way, is this data / layout / query strategy something that
>   resonates well with a NoSQL DB ?

Performance has costs when using NoSQL, many times, you will have to modify your code, your database schema, your server configuration. Are you prepared to pay the price?

Answering your question, I try to avoid MongoDB aggregation, preferring to manually aggregate on the spot (my source code is my SQL), but I do it for small ranges. If doing the entire table/collection, would be better to use Map-Reduce or Aggregation or custom code? It depends, who is doing the job faster?

Most of the time, people will advise to denormalize your data, but doing this can cause another range of issues. Again, pay the price.

Answer (score 1):

`MongoDB` documents are similar to [JSON](https://www.json.org/) objects.The values of fields may include other documents, arrays, and arrays of documents.Even a record in `MongoDB` is a document, which is a data structure composed of `field` and `value` pairs.

```
{"field": "value"}
```

The advantages of using documents in `MongoDB` are:

1. `Documents (i.e. objects) correspond to native data types in many`
   `programming languages`.
2. `Embedded documents and arrays reduce need for`
       **expensive joins**.
3. `Dynamic schema supports fluent polymorphism`.

While **Aggregation** operations group values from multiple documents together, and can perform a variety of operations on the grouped data to return a single result.

As in your case mention as aggregation code like

```
db.getCollection('a').aggregate(
    [{ $sort:
        {"description.location": 1}
     },
     { $group:
        {_id: "$description.location"}
     }]
)
```

Even from MongoDB 3.6 some of new aggregation operator [Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/) has introduced like `position operator` & `$expr`, through which you can **improve your query**.

For further your ref [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) and [Introduction to MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/introduction/)

Comment: Thanks! I read those and we certainly were looking at a NoSQL solution due to the need to reduce the number of joins we are currently doing. How exactly can those operators improve my query ?

Comment: @Chris,$positional Operator,$expr Query Operator & Array Update Improvements , change streams,updateLookup and aggregation pipeline etc